# Components of the algebraic set $XY = 0$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X = (x_{ij}), Y = (y_{ij})$ be $n \times n$ matrices over $k = \bar k$. What do the irreducible components of the algebraic set defined by the equations $XY = 0$ (this is a subset of $\mathbb{A}^{2n^2}_\mathbb{C}$) look like?

My thoughts: The points in this set obviously correspond to matrices $X, Y$ with $XY = 0$. Since $k$ has no zero divisors, we must have $\det(X) = 0$ or $\det(Y) = 0$. Now if, say, $X$ is singular we require $Y$ to be $n$ column vectors which are killed by $X$. In particular, on the algebraic set defined by $rk(X) \leq r$, then the null space of $X$ is $n-r$ dimensional, so one would expect to have a $n(n-r)$ dimensional set for what $Y$ can be ($n-r$ dimensions for each of the $n$ choices of column vector).

So we have $2n$ (not necessarily disjoint) pieces: with $rk(X) \leq r$ for each $0 \leq r \leq n$ and $Y$ being $n$ column vectors killed by $X$ and then $rk(Y) \leq r$ for $0 \leq r \leq n$ and $X$ being $n$ row vectors killed by $Y$. How can I find the components from this? I don't think these are the components since, for example, each of the $n$ column vectors don't really "depend" on each other, so one should be able to reduce each of the above pieces into at least $n$ others.